# how to model this datamodel without to much space?

Tags: java

I'm writing this question because I dont know how to model this dataModel which I need right.

First of all, this is what I have (**I simplyfied it a bit**):
I have a `List<Foo> list;` where Foo has three attributes:

```
public class Foo {
    public int one;
    public int two;
    public long three;
}
```

now I have a other `List<int> list2;`

the most important thing: the first item in `list` and the first in `list2` are corresponding.

**What I want to get:**
I want to have a structure, wher I can enter the one,two,three and then get the corresponding `int`

I tired this:
I found out the max values of one, two and three and then created a `int[maxOne][maxTwo][maxThree]` and filled it in a loop:

```
int count = 0;
int[][][] daten = new int[maxOne][maxTwo][maxThree];
for (Foo foo : list)
{
    daten[foo.one][foo.two][foo.three] = list2[count];
    count++;
}
```

but this is a bad idea because the `new int[maxOne][maxTwo][maxThree];` need very much memory and not every value in this 3 dimensinal array is needed.

So what is your recommondation?

Comment: Simply travel through `list`. Or build an **Binary Search Tree** if performance is an issue.

Comment: Create objects, put associations, don't use multidimentional structures.

Comment: I think you can use [SparceArray](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array)

Comment: I'm not realy sure about what you want, but you could use a HashMap using your Foo object as a key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `HashMap<Foo, Integer>`; just be sure to override `hashcode` and `equals` in `Foo` (`equals` should be easy enough, see [this article](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/10/override-hashcode-in-java-example.html) for an example of overriding `hashcode`)

Comment: ok I made a HashMap and the override of the two methods, but how to get the element when I need to create my own Foo before? the HashMap dont have s.th. like: getEquals, it just have the get

Comment: You'll need to retrieve the value with something like `map.get(new Foo(one, two, three))` - you'll need to create the necessary constructor in `Foo`